# Fancyheaders and special pages: contents, bibliography

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I use the `fancyhdr` package and it works in general. Unfortunately, some "special" pages' headers, like those of the contents and bibliography, seem to resist every approach to format them. They show an uppercase "CONTENTS" and "BIBLIOGRAPHY" instead of the lowercase headers of the rest of the document. How can I configure their appearance or, in particular, make them lowercase?

An example shows what I mean when you compile it:

```
\documentclass[twoside, openright]{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

% Setup fancyhdr
\pagestyle{fancy} % Use fancy headers
\fancyhf{} % Clear all header and footer entries
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\chaptername\ \thechapter.\ #1}{}} % how the chapter is supposed to be displayed in the headers
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}} % how the section is supposed to be displayed in the headers
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.1ex} % Head line
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.1ex} % Foot line
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage} % Footer
\fancyhead[LE]{\textit{\leftmark}} % Header
\fancyhead[RO]{\textit{\rightmark}} % Header
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhf{}\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0ex}} % Redefine plain style, it is used for pages with new chapters

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{chapter 1}
\chapter{chapter 2}
\chapter{chapter 3}
\chapter{chapter 4}
\chapter{chapter 5}
\chapter{chapter 6}
\chapter{chapter 7}
\nocite{*} \bibliography{?} % insert your own bibliography here or comment it out

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Search the documentation of `fancyhdr` for the `\nouppercase` command. Or alternatively use other package like `titleps`.

Comment: Would you like to give an example of code?

Comment: Thank you. Quick solution: replace `\fancyhead[LE]{\textit{\leftmark}}` and
`\fancyhead[RO]{\textit{\rightmark}}` with `\fancyhead[LE]{\textit{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}}` and
`\fancyhead[RO]{\textit{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}}`, respectively, in my example.

Comment: Just one thing does not work: "List of Figures" has a capital "F", whereas everything else has only a capital first letter. Do you know how to change it?

Comment: Simply adding `\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{List of figures}` works.